# facebook API authentication query parameter special character issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spring-mvc

I'm calling facebook authentication API

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=3768637750&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login.html?loginType=facebook

I get back following response.

=">http://localhost:8080/login.html?loginType=facebook&code=AQA84TrJjJNQaib2qvhGSdrPIIwJoIlfs9ZABjhBO6H9vt2wSZuRedigWjgV8SMg7QafCq-0xgbvi5k1e-RtFNA1pbrcfSsIqBL__-YWWhVFFepTGUuJeXWPW8Z3orRl-fWJUqb2mnmAJ995VFVX3O9N4iDj_3mhgQLC0DVwegprezqV6fU1tElMpH5Gj0#*=*

I'm using Spring3.0, and when is use some method like getCode() to read query parameter in Controller, I get truncated value for query paramter "code"

instead of getting,
AQA84TrJjJNQaib2qvhGSdrPIIwJoIlfs9ZABjhBO6H9vt2wSZuRedigWjgV8SMg7QafCq-0xgbvi5k1e-RtFNA1pbrcfSsIqBL__-YWWhVFFepTGUuJeXWPW8Z3orRl-fWJUqb2mnmAJ995VFVX3O9N4iDj_3mhgQLC0DVwegprezqV6fU1tElMpH5Gj0#*=*

I get
AQA84TrJjJNQaib2qvhGSdrPIIwJoIlfs9ZABjhBO6H9vt2wSZuRedigWjgV8SMg7QafCq-0xgbvi5k1e-RtFNA1pbrcfSsIqBL__-YWWhVFFepTGUuJeXWPW8Z3orRl-fWJUqb2mnmAJ995VFVX3O9N4iDj_3mhgQLC0DVwegprezqV6fU1tElMpH5Gj0

I am using UTF-8 encoding, any help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using UTF-8 encoding

That doesn’t matter, since this is not a character encoding issue.

A hash # in an URL marks the start of the “fragment identifier”, and that does *not* get passed to the server.

> I get truncated value for query paramter "code"

There *is* no truncation, because the value of the code parameter ends before the #.